# How can I allow user to pay by credit card without inputing customer information?

Tags: paypal

We are using the plan called "Website Payment Pro". It works. However, it requires too many inputs from customers (Like billing information, see following image for details), is there anyway we can get rid of them? Thanks.

[image]

Cheers,
Ron

Comment: can you please give me the link for the demo code for this payment integration? I am looking for the same.

Comment: The image you're displaying here is for Express Checkout, not Payments Pro.  Pro would be either the DoDirectPayment API or the PayFlow API.  In either case, you would be building your own checkout form instead of using PayPal's.  That would be for people who specifically chose to pay with a CC.  If they choose PayPal, then you'd send them through this Express Checkout flow, where in most cases they would just be logging in.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, probably you are right, it is express checkout. So you mean it is NOT possible to get rid of these business info inputs?

Comment: @Manthan, right now I still don't figure out. I will let you know when my case is done.

Comment: @Ron, not with Express Checkout, no.  If you're using Pro, just build the credit card form into your own page.  Then you won't be redirecting to PayPal at all.  You would just process your own form directly with the API.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, Yes you are right.